# How to work remotely on Windows 8 from Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, vnc, windows-8, remote-access

How can I work remotely on Windows 8 machine from my Ubuntu 10.04 PC?

Is there any guide how to set up remote desktop and VNC this way?
(I don't want to use TeamViewer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [TightVNC](http://www.tightvnc.com/download.php)!

There is a Java-standalone client to use on different systems.
You don't need the TightVNC-server to use the client.

If you wan't to use it over the internet use [Dynamic DNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_DNS) to connect to your network.

If you stay in the same network everything should be fine just with a VNC server + client.